# How to grant user who can commit directly to protected branch on GitHub

Tags: github, git-push

I am using a repository which has a protected branch.
How to grant an user who can commit directly to protected branch on GitHub.
I am admin so I don't want to grant other guide to become a admin (Who can delete the repository)

[image: User can't commit directly]

Comment: Is this an organization repository or a personal repository?

Comment: This is an organization repository private.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give the user "write" permission, instead of full "admin" permission. See https://help.github.com/articles/repository-permission-levels-for-an-organization/.

Comment: I solved it. I used a personal access token from admin.
https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line/